# Identify a short story about a wall at the edge of the universe

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Two astronauts arrive at the edge of the universe and find a wall. There is graffiti on the wall, including "Kilroy was here". There is a coin slot that opens a portal to look through the wall. One of the astronauts takes a look and tells the other there is nothing there.

The story was very short and probably written in the 1960s.

Comment: This is ringing a faint bell. Were the astronauts in a computer simulation and the wall was the edge of the simulation?

Comment: No, not a simulation. Also, there was graffiti on the wall, including Kilroy was here. The story was very short and probably written in the 1960s.

Comment: Oh well, there goes that theory :-(

Comment: BOOM! The mention of “Kilroy was here” did the trick! It's funny how the smallest details can jog your memory.

Comment: The title made me think of Wit's tale from the *The Stormlight Archive*.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Ado About Nothing](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?832535) by Robert K. Ottum. It was originally published in The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction March 1965 but I read it in The Year's Best SF 11th Annual Edition.

It starts:

> Today we reached the end of the universe. It was a big sign with red letters all lit up.
>
> this is the end of the universe-  do not proceed beyond this point
>
> We pulled the ship in close and cut all the power. Frank hollered over the intercom: “What in the hell is this?”

and it ends:

> When I got about twenty feet away from the wall, I could see them. There were hundreds of them, plastered all over it. Old signs. There was an “Eat At Joe’s,” and a great big “Kilroy was here,” and hearts with names in them. As I got closer, I could even see the hand-scrawled four-letter words with crude drawings.
>
> As I got right up against the wall, I noticed the little white square sign. It said,
>
> "obviously you are not convinced that this is the end of the universe. if you will place a quarter in the slot below, the peep-hole will open, and you can see for yourself."
>
> And the captain was right. I paid my quarter and looked through the peep-hole. But it was nothing.